# How to do pagination in nodejs+express+mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using nodejs+express+mongodb. I am working on api. I want to do the pagination in nodejs+express.
Note: there is mongoose-pagination option but I am not using mongoose. I am using direct mongodb only.

Please tel me how can I do the pagination in nodejs+express. I got this link [express-paginate](https://github.com/expressjs/express-paginate)

But I could not work on it. I dont know How can I implement it in my API.

Here is JSON data. In this steps arrays listing more than 10 so I want to do pagination for this.

Here is my API. Here inside steps for loop, I added given(in the above github link) pagination code

```
const get = (req, res, next) => {
applogger.verbose(`retrieving asdsa with id ${req.params.asd}`);
asd.findOneById(req.params.asd)
    .then(function(resp) {
        for (var i = 0; i < resp.steps.length; i++) {
            if (resp.asd[i].image == null) {
                resp.asd[i].image = imgurl;
            }

            asd.paginate({}, { page: req.query.page, limit: req.query.limit }, function(err, users) {

                if (err) return next(err);

                res.format({
                    json: function() {
                        res.json('users', {
                            users: users.docs,
                            pageCount: users.pages,
                            itemCount: users.limit,
                            pages: paginate.getArrayPages(req)(3, users.pages, req.query.page)
                        });
                    },
                    json: function() {
                        // inspired by Stripe's API response for list objects
                        res.json({
                            object: 'list',
                            has_more: paginate.hasNextPages(req)(users.pages),
                            data: users.docs
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        if (resp.asd == null) {
            resp.asd = imgurl;
        }
        res.json(resp);
    }, function(err) {
        res.send(err);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 8):

Use your mongo aggregation / find, etc... and just apply the skip and limit operator.

if you want to display X result by page and if you are the page number N (starting from 0)

```
MyCollection.find([
    ...
])
.skip(X * N)
.limit(X)
.exec(function(err, result){
```

///

```
 Tourtle.find({})
 .skip(req.skip)
 .limit(req.query.limit)
 .exec(function(err, users) {
    if(err) .... else .....
  });
```

Comment: Hi, Can you give little more explanation. can you show me how can I implenet it in my code. Should I remove the added express-paginate code(after for loop I added)

Comment: See edit. No you can keep it. Just replace the Tourle.paginate with the find

Comment: Sorry to say. Still I could not do it. Can you use my code and modify? and please upload?

Comment: replace this "
            Tourtle.paginate({}, { page: req.query.page, limit: req.query.limit }, function(err, users) {

                if (err) return next(err);
" with the code above.

Comment: But your code is totaly wrong. You perform async operation in a for and then call res.json. You need to replace the for with an async for like (async.eachOf https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html)

Answer (score 3):

In your client you need to do a pagination like:

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li><a href="/yourRoute/1">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/yourRoute/2">2</a></li>
</ul>
```

and your back-end be like:

```
const getTourtle = (req, res, next) => {
    var page = req.params.id;
    var minPage = 10 * (page - 1);
    var maxPage = minPage + 10;
    db.collection.find({
         //do your query
    }).min({_id:min_page}).max({_id:max_page});

    res.json(resp); // send response to client
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am not using any view page. I am not using client side. Now I am working on API. I want display it in API like how json data displays in browser there it pagination should display. Please see the screen shot above.